# How to write unit tests for for javascript 'plugin' (iframe) that expects certain global variables to be present

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, iframe, trello

I am working on a [Trello Power Up](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#power-ups-intro). The way they work is they load an iFrame you provide with some `script` tags that contain your custom code. You can see a working example [here](https://glitch.com/~trello-power-up-skeleton). The upshot is that when your code runs, there are certain "global" (not even sure if that's the right word) objects present that you interact with. For example:

```
const Promise = TrelloPowerUp.Promise;

TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
  'card-buttons': (t, options) => {
    return [{
      text: 'Awesome Button',
    }];
  }, 'show-settings': (t, options) =>{
    return t.popup({
      title: 'Settings',
      url: './settings.html',
      height: 184 // we can always resize later, but if we know the size in advance, its good to tell Trello
    });
  }
});
```

I am starting to add a little bit of complexity to this project and my habit is to use tdd/ write unit tests. I can't figure out how this code would be testable.

Is there some way to provide a mock 'TrelloPowerUp' global object before I run a mocha test? I tried:

```
TrelloPowerUp = {}
require('./client.js');
```

(The client.js script runs as soon as it is imported...) Unsurprisingly that didn't work.

I suppose I could import from another file that did have unit tests, to minimize the untestable code, something like:

import TrelloInitActions from './TrelloInitActions'

```
const Promise = TrelloPowerUp.Promise;

TrelloPowerUp.initialize({
  'card-buttons': TrelloInitActions.initButtons
}, 'show-settings': TrelloInitActions.showSettings
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I am using react, if you find yourself in this situation check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/trello-react-scripts